# Updating customer details

Tags: database-design

I have a website which stores customer details, name, address, contact etc. A customer can update their own details via a form. What are the best practices for implementing this?

Do I just use an `UPDATE` statement over the existing data, or do I have *old* and *new* details?

It got me thinking, say if using a webiste such as amazon when a customer updates their details. What if the details are not correct? Do amazon have a record of the old details as a backup?

Such as a customer could live at 999 Fake Street. Also what if a problem occurs and the customer cannot be contacted because of the new updated details given? For example the customer receives a service and avoid paying.

Should I just update customers information, or should I move the old data into another table then update?

Hope I haven't asked too much of an obvious question, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to keep a history of user profile changes, or how to make sure they enter the correct information?  It sounds like your question is more along the lines of ensuring the user enters correct information, which is more of a interface design question than a data question.

Comment: Am asking abit of both really, is it ok to just update customers details or should I make a backup before allowing them to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elliott,  the database design you are seeking must be based on business rules.  The DBA at facebook, twitter, amazon or Mom's Pizza did not dedtermine how many old addresses to keep.  Ask the BA for the rule on address.  If the answer is "keep only a current address"  then implement the **UPDATE** statement you mentioned in the question.  If the BA give you a blank stare then insert new rows for every update and display the latest chrono record and NEVER delete anything.

When the DB A recieves a complete set of business rules only then should the design begin.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to your customer table `InfoDate` or something similar.  Then you can access the data via a view that only shows  you the record for each customer where the `InfoDate` is  the max value for that customer.

You keep all your data without a complicated process of migrating to another table for archiving, and you can access historical data easily by directly querying the table instead of the view.

Comment: Thanks, is  there an actual need to store the data before being updated? Data protection Act states "not kept longer than necessary", it wouldn't be necessary unless i'm actually using it?

Comment: There probably is not a need to store EVERY entry for every customer.  You could make the case that you need at least 1 historical record per customer in case of an error.  If a customer mis-keys some information, having an option to go back is good.  I'm not a UK legal expert, though, just making a suggestion for your data model.